Knights tour chess board
In this image

you can see the tour of a knight on a 6 $\times$ 6 chessboard. The special thing is that this route is identical when you rotate if by $90$ degrees. I wanted to implement this in Latex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) grid (6,6);

\fill[gray!20] (0,5) rectangle (1,6); % (1, 9)
\fill[gray!20] (1,4) rectangle (2,5); % (2, 30)
\fill[gray!20] (2,3) rectangle (3,4); % (3, 15)
\fill[gray!20] (3,2) rectangle (4,3); % (4, 22)
\fill[gray!20] (4,1) rectangle (5,2); % (5, 7)
\fill[gray!20] (5,0) rectangle (6,1); % (6, 36)

\fill[gray!20] (1,5) rectangle (2,6); % (16)
\fill[gray!20] (3,4) rectangle (4,5); % (8)
\fill[gray!20] (5,3) rectangle (6,4); % (1)

\fill[gray!20] (0,3) rectangle (1,4); % (21)
\fill[gray!20] (2,2) rectangle (3,3); % (29)
\fill[gray!20] (4,1) rectangle (5,2); % (14)

\node at (0.5,5.5) {9};
\node at (1.5,5.5) {16};
\node at (2.5,5.5) {31};
\node at (3.5,5.5) {24};
\node at (4.5,5.5) {3};
\node at (5.5,5.5) {18};

\node at (0.5,4.5) {30};
\node at (1.5,4.5) {23};
\node at (2.5,4.5) {10};
\node at (3.5,4.5) {17};
\node at (4.5,4.5) {32};
\node at (5.5,4.5) {25};

\node at (0.5,3.5) {15};
\node at (1.5,3.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,3.5) {29};
\node at (3.5,3.5) {2};
\node at (4.5,3.5) {19};
\node at (5.5,3.5) {4};

\node at (0.5,2.5) {22};
\node at (1.5,2.5) {1};
\node at (2.5,2.5) {20};
\node at (3.5,2.5) {11};
\node at (4.5,2.5) {26};
\node at (5.5,2.5) {33};

\node at (0.5,1.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,1.5) {14};
\node at (2.5,1.5) {35};
\node at (3.5,1.5) {28};
\node at (4.5,1.5) {5};
\node at (5.5,1.5) {12};

\node at (0.5,0.5) {36};
\node at (1.5,0.5) {21};
\node at (2.5,0.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,0.5) {13};
\node at (4.5,0.5) {34};
\node at (5.5,0.5) {27};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But my output

is not as I wanted it to be. I know I only took one color tone but the main problems are the lines and that the color is not inside the squares like in the picture. Any ideas on how to fix that?

move the \draw[thick] (0,0) grid (6,6); to the end.

Thanks to @UlrikeFischer, I completed the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[gray!100] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[gray!100] (0,4) rectangle (1,5);
\fill[gray!100] (2,1) rectangle (3,2);
\fill[gray!100] (2,3) rectangle (3,4);
\fill[gray!100] (2,5) rectangle (3,6);
\fill[gray!100] (3,1) rectangle (4,2);
\fill[gray!100] (4,0) rectangle (5,1);
\fill[gray!100] (4,4) rectangle (5,5);
\fill[gray!100] (5,2) rectangle (6,3);

\fill[gray!70] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\fill[gray!70] (0,2) rectangle (1,3);
\fill[gray!70] (1,4) rectangle (2,5);
\fill[gray!70] (5,0) rectangle (6,1);
\fill[gray!70] (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
\fill[gray!70] (3,5) rectangle (4,6);
\fill[gray!70] (5,4) rectangle (6,5);
\fill[gray!70] (4,3) rectangle (5,4);
\fill[gray!70] (4,2) rectangle (5,3);

\fill[gray!30] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[gray!30] (5,5) rectangle (6,6);
\fill[gray!30] (0,3) rectangle (1,4);
\fill[gray!30] (1,5) rectangle (2,6);
\fill[gray!30] (2,4) rectangle (3,5);
\fill[gray!30] (3,4) rectangle (4,5);
\fill[gray!30] (3,2) rectangle (4,3);
\fill[gray!30] (3,0) rectangle (4,1);
\fill[gray!30] (5,1) rectangle (6,2);


\node at (0.5,5.5) {9};
\node at (1.5,5.5) {16};
\node at (2.5,5.5) {31};
\node at (3.5,5.5) {24};
\node at (4.5,5.5) {3};
\node at (5.5,5.5) {18};

\node at (0.5,4.5) {30};
\node at (1.5,4.5) {23};
\node at (2.5,4.5) {10};
\node at (3.5,4.5) {17};
\node at (4.5,4.5) {32};
\node at (5.5,4.5) {25};

\node at (0.5,3.5) {15};
\node at (1.5,3.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,3.5) {29};
\node at (3.5,3.5) {2};
\node at (4.5,3.5) {19};
\node at (5.5,3.5) {4};

\node at (0.5,2.5) {22};
\node at (1.5,2.5) {1};
\node at (2.5,2.5) {20};
\node at (3.5,2.5) {11};
\node at (4.5,2.5) {26};
\node at (5.5,2.5) {33};

\node at (0.5,1.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,1.5) {14};
\node at (2.5,1.5) {35};
\node at (3.5,1.5) {28};
\node at (4.5,1.5) {5};
\node at (5.5,1.5) {12};

\node at (0.5,0.5) {36};
\node at (1.5,0.5) {21};
\node at (2.5,0.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,0.5) {13};
\node at (4.5,0.5) {34};
\node at (5.5,0.5) {27};
\draw[thick] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


